# TypeScript Class Generic Parameter Constraints

Tags: typescript

I'm attempting to declare a TypeScript class with a constrained generic parameter. In C#, the following would compile:

```
public class NewClass<T> where T: BaseClass {
}
```

What is the TypeScript equivalent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For both classes and interfaces as base, you have to constrain `T` like this:

```
export class NewClass<T extends BaseClass> {
}
```

While you derive classes from interfaces with `implements`, the same is not true for generic constraints, making this code possible:

```
export class NewClass<T extends BaseInterface> implements BaseInterface {
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for the `extends` keyword. You can use it right after the generic parameter to constrain it to be a subtype of the specified type.

So the equivalent for your example would be:

```
class NewClass<T extends BaseClass> {
    // Things...
}
```

You can read more about generic constraints in the [documentation here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints).

Comment: Rant: I found the documentation on Generics, and on TypeScript in general, to be very difficult to parse. Which is why I ultimately posted the question - if you visit the c# page, it is extremely easy to tell how to do this. Not true in TypeScript.